# Xcode 10 button to create mad lips story will not run, I'm new to Xcode

Tags: swift, button

I'm just starting out with Xcode 10 and cannot get this button to work for my mad libs creation. this is just for fun but I would love to know how to fix it. Please look over my code to see why the "create story" button is not active.

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  Field Button Fun
//
//  Created by Audrey Chao on 8/3/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Maddie Chao. All rights reserved.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var thePlace: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var theVerb: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var theNumber: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var theTemplate: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var theStory: UITextView!

    @IBAction func createStory(sender: AnyObject) {
        theStory.text = theTemplate.text
        theStory.text = theStory.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<place>", withString: thePlace.text!)
        theStory.text =   theStory.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<verb>", withString:   theVerb.text!)
 theStory.text =         theStory.text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<number>", withString:         theNumber.text!)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //thePlace.resignFirstResponder()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a       nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you wired up the action? In other words, you need to tell Interface Builder that `createStory` is the action for this button.

Comment: What do you mean by "not active"?

Comment: @Sweeper I think she just means that when you click it, nothing happens.

Comment: There is no Xcode 10 yet

Answer (score 0):

Have you wired up your button to your IBAction? If they aren't wired up, Xcode won't be able to tell what your button is supposed to do.